# MATLAB Bar Graph: How to combine bar graphs?

Tags: matlab

Sorry for this simple question, but I am having trouble figuring out how to combine bar graphs on MATLAB. Right now, I have the following two bar graphs which I am trying to combine:

First

[image: first]

Second

[image]

All I want to do is combine the two graphs such that all the information stays the same and the only difference is that all the sigmas and gammas are on the same x-axis. Can someone please help me or show me a reference where I could find the answer to this question?

Thank you

Comment: create one bar graph combining the data of both the bar graphs you have. example - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#bthxcel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the examples on [Bar graph](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#bug9u7m-1) in Matlab. You can either use **group of bars** or **stacked bars** but i guess what you need is **group of bars**. I am one example here.

Example: Use `bar(...)` to get the type of results you want. Consider the following code with results shown below:

```
% Make some play data:
x = randn(100,3);
[y, b] = hist(x);

% You can plot on your own bar chart:
figure(82);
bar(b,y,'grouped');
title('Grouped bar chart');

% Consider stack for the other type:
figure(83);
bar(b,y,'stacked');
title('Stacked bar chart');
```

[image]

[image]

You can also use `hist(...)`:

```
% Bust histogram will work here:
figure(44);
hist(x);
title('Histogram Automatically Grouping');
```

[image]

> Update

You can plot a single bar graph by combining the data of both the bar plots you have. You can set the x-axis values as you want. See this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#bthxcel). To set axis values in `Bar graph`, you can see this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGEK5fhiZSA).

Comment: Thank you for your response, and I have looked at that Matlab page. However, all I am trying to do is replicate this graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWURP.png  I have the code for both the bar graphs using sigmas and using gammas, but I'm not sure how to combine them.

Comment: is it the correct way to do what you want to do? you are putting two variables along x-axis. does it make sense? anyway, what you can do is just plot a single bar graph by combining the data of both the bar plots you have. you can set the x-axis values as well. just look into the example of single bar graph.